# Why Didn't This Condition Trigger?

Tags: c#

I have a robot stock trading program that I've been working on for a few months. The other day though I added a 2nd condition to the code that determines when the trade gets exited. Condition as follows:

```
decimal entryPrice;
decimal CurrentPrice;
decimal openShares;


if ((1st condition) && (((entryPrice - CurrentPrice) * openShares) >= 8))
```

Today was the first day the situation came up, and I happened to have the day off work so I was observing the trades. The condition didn't trigger though. The trade kept going until I manually exited.

What should have happened is that it would subtract the current price from the price at time of entry, then multiply that by the number of shares to get the current profit. And if it's greater than or equal to 8, it triggers. This particular code was only for exiting short trades, so subtracting the current price from the entry price should return a positive value.

I verified in my code that the entryPrice was being logged at time of purchase. So all I can think is that I'm messing something up with the condition format. Either it doesn't like the bracket arrangement or the resulting number value types aren't compatible with each other. Does anything jump out at you? Thanks.

Comment: if i understand what you are asking it means today both condition1 and condition 2 were true? right?

Comment: Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() is your friend. Before the evaluation, print out all of the values etc.

Comment: You should try to create a [mcve], include example values for the 3 decimals (you should try to compare them to a decimal too `8m`)

Comment: If you want an answer to your question: it didn't trigger because either `1st condition` evaluated to `false`, or because `((entryPrice - CurrentPrice) * openShares)` was less than `8`. You really need to give a complete example if you want help here. We're not  fortune tellers

Comment: Both conditions were true. So I'm running on the assumption that my formatting is wrong somehow.

Comment: **Write a large body of unit tests**.  Observe your code under test conditions and make sure it is doing what you expect it to do; if it is not, then you have a test you can use to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the exact cause, but if your "1st condition" is false, the second condition will not be evaluated at all for many languages.
So please make sure the '1st condition' is true.

After that, if the problem still exist, you can print out some log messages about the variable values to see what's going on.

Comment: The first condition is true when the target price is met (on a different stock than the one being traded) and it was true and then some in this particular case. So the 2nd condition should have been evaluated too.

Answer (score 0):

Change your conditional to

```
if(true){
//code after the conditional 
}
```

If this executes, Then something isn't getting set properly inside your brackets.
`(((entryPrice - CurrentPrice) * openShares) >= 8)`
This is your second part of the condition. Parenthesis match up, however, I do not know what's happening inside the conditional. Since you're multiplying, it very easily could be constantly greater than 8. (maybe you meant less than?)

Try printing out some values, and see where that leads you. Print out your first condition, then your second condition.

If you have support for implicit conversions, try using BITWISE AND (&) rather than LOGICAL AND (&&).

This way, the second condition will be 'resolved' to a variable. (i.e. ran)